# Fiber of covering map is orbit of deck transformation group

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

**Some definitions:** Let $\lambda: \mathbb H \to \mathbb C \setminus \{-1, +1 \}$ be the covering map, i.e. $\lambda$ is surjective and for every $z \neq \pm 1$ there exists a neighborhood $V_z \subseteq \mathbb C$ such that $\lambda : U_\alpha \to V_z$ is a biholomorphism for each connected component $U_\alpha$ of $\lambda^{-1} (V_z)$. Let $G$ be the decking transformations, i.e. automorphisms of the upper half plane $T: \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$ satisfying $\lambda(Tz) = \lambda(z)$. Clearly this forms a group under composition.

I want to show that, for every $z \in \mathbb H$,
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{-1}(\lambda(z)) = \{ Tz : T \in G \}.
\end{equation}
The right hand side is clearly contained in the left, so it remains to show that for every $w \in \mathbb H$ satisfying $\lambda(z) = \lambda(w)$, we have $w = Tz$ for some $T \in G$.

I was able to prove that any $T \in G$ which is not the identity cannot have a fixed point on the fiber, but this isn't good enough to obtain the result. By the Lindelof covering property of the complex plane, the fiber is at most countable. If it were finite, then maybe some pigeonhole-type argument could be used, but this seems to be a dead end avenue.

Constructing the map explicitly seems a bit difficult since I'm not too sure how $\lambda$ behaves (I'm following [Marshall's Complex Analysis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/complex-analysis/A9F208164B3F4116C03D9714135C5EB7); he constructs the map via an inductive application of the reflection principle), though it seems it's the only avenue left.

Comment: consider the local map that sends $w$ to $z$ through $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{-1}$ and show that it extends to $\mathbb H$ by extending it alongside simple paths from $w$ (again using the properties of $\lambda$ you can cover the path by finitely many open sets on which $\lambda$ biholomorphic etc) to any other point $w_1$ and then using that $\mathbb H$ is simply connected so the end result doesn't depend on path

Comment: You should correct your definition of a covering map: It should be not for "a connected component of $\lambda^{-1}(V_z)$" but "for each connected component $\lambda^{-1}(V_z)$." ("a" stands for "some".)

Comment: @Conrad Ah, I see, so the proof more or less parallels that of Picard's theorem using monodromy. Thanks.

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: @Conrad I have one more question: how would one go about showing that the constructed map is an automorphism of $\mathbb H$? Following the construction of $T$ I think I can show injectivity, though I'm having trouble showing surjectivity.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the holomorphic lifting lemma?

Comment: show that a lifting of a covering map that fixes a point is the identity (the set of fixed points of the lifting of a covering map is open and closed so it is either empty or full space - open uses the covering property, closed true always for continuous maps) and then construct the map $S$ as above that takes $z$ to $w$ and use the above to show that $S$ is the inverse of $T$

Comment: @Conrad I forgot about inverses for some bizarre reason... your method is instructive though I think you can appeal to the uniqueness theorem for holomorphic functions, since $S$ is a local inverse of $T$, it is a global inverse. In any case thanks; I'll try to work out the details of your suggestion as well.

Comment: I agree that you can do it other ways too - depends on what results you are willing to use but the thing with open and close is standard in proving results about analytic functions as usually close holds from continuity and open by some properties of analytic functions (you can prove maximum modulus, identity theorem etc this way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My written up solution for posterity, inspired by the ever so helpful comments by Conrad in the comments: Recall that automorphisms of the upper half plane are Mobius transformations. Let $G$ be the set of automorphisms $T: \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$ satisfying $\lambda(T(z)) = \lambda(z)$, and suppose $T, S \in G$. Then 
        \begin{equation}
 \lambda((T \circ S)(z)) = \lambda(S(z)) = \lambda(z), \qquad \lambda(z) = \lambda((T \circ T^{-1}) (z)) = \lambda(T^{-1} (z)), \end{equation}
    for all $z \in \mathbb H$, i.e. $T \circ S \in G$ and $T^{-1} \in G$. Clearly $G$ contains the identity, so we conclude it is a group under composition. Fix $z \in \mathbb H$, by construction of $G$, we have the inclusion
        \begin{equation} \{ T(z) : T \in G \} \subseteq \lambda^{-1} (\lambda(z)). \end{equation}
    To show equality, we need to show that if $w \in \mathbb H$ satisfies $\lambda(w) = \lambda(z)$, then $T(z) = w$ for some $T \in G$. Since $\lambda$ is a covering map, every $p \in \mathbb C \setminus \{-1, 1\}$ admits a neighborhood $V_p \subseteq \mathbb C$ such that 
        \begin{equation} \lambda: U_i \to V_p \end{equation}
    is a biholomorphism on each connected component $U_i$ of $\lambda^{-1} (V_p)$. For $p = \lambda(z)$, suppose $z \in U_0$ and $w \in U_1$. Denoting $g_0 : V_{\lambda(z)} \to U_1$ the local inverse of $\lambda$, we have
        \begin{equation} \lambda \circ g_0 \circ \lambda = \lambda, \qquad (g_0 \circ \lambda)(z) = w. \end{equation}
    We want to analytically continue $g_0 \circ \lambda: U_0 \to U_1$ to an automorphism on $\mathbb H$. Fix $\zeta \in \mathbb H$ and let $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \mathbb H$ be a continuous curve with initial point $z$ and terminal point $\zeta$. The image $(\lambda \circ \gamma)([0, 1])$ is compact, so the open cover
        \begin{equation} (\lambda \circ \gamma)([0, 1]) \subseteq \bigcup_{t \in [0, 1]} V_{(\lambda \circ \gamma) (t)}\end{equation}
    admits a Lebesgue covering number $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\lambda \circ \gamma$ is uniformly continuous, we can choose a partition of the unit interval $0 = t_0 < \cdots < t_n = 1$ with mesh sufficiently small such that 
        \begin{equation} (\lambda \circ \gamma)([t_i, t_{i + 1}]) \subseteq V_{(\lambda \circ \gamma)(t_i)}. \end{equation}
    For brevity, denote $V_i = V_{(\lambda \circ \gamma)(t_i)}$ and $w_i = (\lambda \circ \gamma)(t_i)$; in particular, $V_0 = V_{\lambda(z)}$. Proceeding inductively, given function element $(g_i \circ \lambda, \lambda^{-1} (V_i))$, we have $w_{i + 1} \in V_i \cap V_{i + 1}$, so $g_i (w_{i + 1}) \in U_{i + 2}$ for some connected component of $\lambda^{-1} (V_{i + 1})$. Denote $g_{i + 1} : V_{i + 1} \to U_{i + 2}$ a local inverse of $\lambda$, then
        \begin{equation} (g_{i} \circ \lambda, \lambda^{-1} (V_i)), \qquad (g_{i + 1} \circ \lambda, \lambda^{-1} (V_{i + 1}))  \end{equation}
    the latter is a direct analytic continuation of the former. This proves $g_0 \circ \lambda$ admits an analytic continuation along $\gamma$. Since $\mathbb H$ is simply connected (in fact, contractible), the monodromy theorem tells us that the terminal analytic continuation does not depend on $\gamma$, so by construction there exists $T: \mathbb H\to \mathbb H$ satisfying 
        \begin{equation} \lambda \circ T = \lambda, \qquad T(z) = w. \end{equation}
    It remains to show that $T$ is an automorphism. Arguing similarly to our construction of $T$, we can construct an analytic map $S: \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$ such that $S = (g_0 \circ \lambda)^{-1}$ on $U_1$. In particular, $T \circ S$ is the identity on an open set $U_0$, so by the uniqueness theorem and connectedness of the upper half plane, $(T \circ S)(z) = z$ for all $z \in \mathbb H$. Hence $T \in G$, completing the proof.